# Visual Studio editor performance - exclude statements from beeing analyzed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a performance issue within Visual Studio.
Intellisense, Quick Actions, etc. take up to 20 seconds until they open.

It turns out, that there is just one very complex EF Linq Query, that slows down everything. As soon as I comment out this query, the editor is super responsive again.

Is there any directive or something, where I can exclude parts of the code from beeing validated (by Analyzers I suppose) in the C# editor, so I don't have to comment out the query everytime I touch the file?

Or any other idea to improve performance in this case?

Comment: Wrap the code you wish to exclude from Intellisense using`#ifndef __INTELLISENSE__`, it will show greyed out in the editor and not be cheked by Intellisense, but will be used during compilation. Oh just realized it's C#, this works for c++, there might be an equivelent.